# Select last reported date SQL

Tags: sql

Hi I have a table with the folliwin data

```
+---------+------------------------+-------+
|filename |Dates                   |LastRDt|
+---------+------------------------+-------+
|Store1   |2018-01-24 12:04:45.397 |       |
|Stroe1   |2012-01-22 12:14:20.997 |       |
|Store2   |2013-01-24 12:20:59.407 |       |
|Store3   |2012-01-21 12:14:20.997 |       |
|Store3   |2013-01-24 12:20:59.407 |       |
+---------+------------------------+-------+
```

I need to create a sentence to get something like this

```
+---------+------------------------+--------------------------+
|Store    |Dates                   |LastRDt                   |
+---------+------------------------+--------------------------+
|Store1   |2018-01-24 12:04:45.397 |2012-01-22 12:14:20.997   |
|Stroe1   |2012-01-22 12:14:20.997 |      NULL                |
|Store2   |2013-01-24 12:20:59.407 |      NULL                |
|Store3   |2012-01-21 12:14:20.997 |      NULL                |
|Store3   |2013-01-24 12:20:59.407 |2012-01-21 12:14:20.997   |
+---------+------------------------+--------------------------+
```

Basically I need the last time that the value appear and have that value as lastRDt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store last date for a given filename to a variable and populate LastRDt column

```
select filename, Dates, lastRDt
from
  (select filename, Dates, 
      IF(@lastf = filename, @lastd, NULL) as lastRDt, 
      @lastd := Dates,
      @lastf := filename
  from test, (select @lastd := NULL, @lastf := NULL) r
  order by filename, Dates) t
  order by 1,2;
```

Answer (score 1):

You seem to want the *previous* read date.  You can use `lag()`:

```
select t.*,
       lag(dates) over (partition by store order by dates) as prev_dates
from t;
```